# Hold reference to Numpy array inside C++ object

Tags: python, boost-python

I want to create C++ wrapper for Numpy array. For that purpose I need to hold reference to Numpy array (for returning it to Python later) and reference to raw data of that array.

For that I've wrote the code:

**C++**

```cpp
// mynumpy.h

#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>

namespace py = boost::python;
namespace np = boost::python::numpy;

class MyNumpy
    {
    private:
        np::ndarray* _pydata;
        unsigned char* _data;
    public:
        MyNumpy(np::ndarray& pydata);
        np::ndarray const& numpy();
    };
```

```cpp
// mynumpy.cpp
#include "mynumpy.h"

namespace py = boost::python;
namespace np = boost::python::numpy;

MyNumpy::MyNumpy(np::ndarray& pydata)
    {
        _pydata = &pydata;
        _data = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pydata.get_data());
    }

    np::ndarray const& MyNumpy::numpy()
    {
        return *_pydata;
    }

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    np::initialize();

    py::class_<MyNumpy>("MyNumpy", py::init<np::ndarray&>())
        .def("numpy", &MyNumpy::numpy, py::return_value_policy<py::copy_const_reference>());
}
```

**Python**

```py
import numpy as np
import test

data = np.array([0])
mynp = test.MyNumpy(data)
print(mynp.numpy())
```

But the following Python code seems to crash silently when trying to call `mynp.numpy()`. I've noticed that after calling the constructor, `_pydata` points to empty Python object. I'm not sure how am I supposed to hold those references.

Comment: Keep in mind `np::ndarray` is a C++ object used to adapt the Python type to C++ during the call. I wouldn't expect it to live much longer than the C++ constructor call, and you're storing a pointer to it for much longer than that. Look at it this way -- you invoke the Boost.Python generated wrapper, with Python object as a parameter. The generated code constructs a temporary `np::ndarray` wrapping the Python object. Then it calls your constructor. The constructor returns, the wrapper function ends and temporary goes out of scope. Control returns to Python and you're left with dangling pointer.

Comment: Solution is simple -- instead of a pointer, store `np::ndarray` by value (it's only a thin wrapper around the reference counted Python object). Unless you perform an explicit deep copy, it will still point to the same numpy array. What it will do, is ensure that the numpy array doesn't get deallocated for the lifetime of your `MyNumpy` instance.